# .htaccess redirect specific domain ending to folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i have several domains (same name, but different endings) for the different languages. the .com domain is the main domain and has for each language a directory like /en/

now i want to redirect each of these domains ( e.g. http://example.us/ ) to http://example.com/en/
is this possible with the .htaccess file?

actual i only have a redirection from www.example.com to http://example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you want only `example.us` to redirect (externally) to `example.com/en/` ?

Comment: yes (and the .fr domain to /fr/ and so on)

Comment: Could you make a complete list of all the domains you want to redirect ? Because i guess the last part is always the same as directory, except for `us` to `en` ?

Comment: not at all (like `.at` or `.ch` to `/de/` ), i thought i can list them seperate in the .htaccess?

Comment: Well yes but please post each domain extension you want to redirect and where to. Example: `if want .at and .ch to go to /de/, i want us to go to /en/, etc...`

Comment: at the moment there are only these, but i mainly want to understand how to redirect these domain endings to the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.(at|ch)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/de/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.us$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/en/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But if you have more domains (maybe a lot) you could use `RewriteMap`